# Copy file to clipboard Node.JS

Tags: node.js, shell, electron

Are there anyway to copy a file to clipboard (like cmd+c in Finder).

I want to do this with Electron, I think that a shell script will help.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the clipboard api.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/clipboard.md#clipboard

The write and read buffer is currently experimental.

Comment: The clipboard API you linked can be used to copy text, but how does it copy files? Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Now supports also html, image, rtf and bookmarks. Not all OS supported, see docs.